# How to display certain selected words bolder in asp:hyperlink text

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have a asp:repeater control on my .aspx and in the code behind I am binding its datasource to a Collection of type `KeyValuePair[]<Literal,String>`. I was choosing literal so that I could surround selected words in literal text with `<strong>` or `<b>` html tag. Well I succeeded in doing it but I am not finding a way to display the literal text in the `asp:hyperlink`'s Text part of `asp:repeater`

My .aspx code is as follow:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repLinks" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <div onclick="window.open('<%# ((KeyValuePair<Literal,string>)Container.DataItem).Value %>','_blank');">
               <div>
                   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  NavigateUrl="<%# ((KeyValuePair<Literal,string>)Container.DataItem).Value %>" Text="<%#((KeyValuePair<Literal,string>)Container.DataItem).Key.Text %>"
                       Font-Size='Large' ForeColor='Blue' Font-Names="Open Sans" CssClass="linkstyle" />
                   <br />
               </div>
           </div>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

I need help on how to display the `.Key.Text` part in `asp:Hyperlink`.

I added the keyValuePair as follow:

```
char[] seperator = { ' ' };
String[] explodedString = Results1[index].Key.Split(seperator);
List<String> Query= new List<string>(TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToLowerInvariant().Split(seperator,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
for (int i = 0; i < explodedString.Length; i++)
    {
       if (Query.Contains(explodedString[i].ToLowerInvariant()) == true)
          {
               explodedString[i] = "<strong>" + explodedString[i] + "<strong>";
          }
    }
 Literal temp = new Literal();
 temp.Text = explodedString.ToString();
 TryCurrentWindow[index] = new KeyValuePair<Literal, string>(temp, Results1[index].Value);
```

Here **TryCurrentWindow** is the KeyValuePair[] and `explodedstring[]` is the text string splitted by `'' char` which I want to modify and Query[] is list of my keyWords

Comment: Can you give example what you expect in the output for a given input key Text?

Comment: Also can you post code, how you create `KeyValuePair[]` collection?

Comment: Suppose key words are 'united' and 'alliance' and the text in 'united progressive alliance' I need the output as '**united** progressive **alliance**'

Comment: As **code was too long to post here**, I will try to explain in short, as soon as I get my text, I split it into a string array and compare each string with my key words and if they match I surround them with `<strong>` tag and store this modified text into a `asp:Literal` text and the add it to the keyValuePair<Literal,String> where the key part is the text I am interested in and value part is some description String

Comment: You can edit the post and add code there.

Comment: Few variable requires more explanation but still I have identified how you join `explodedString` again. See answer below and tell if it works?

Comment: Have you tried given solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**:

1. You are not closing `<strong>` tag like this `</strong>`.
2. You are simply doing `ToString()` to `string[]` array.

Updated this line:

```
 explodedString[i] = "<strong>" + explodedString[i] + "</strong>";
```

Also change below code:

```
Literal temp = new Literal();
temp.Text = explodedString.ToString();
```

**With this**:

```
Literal temp = new Literal();
temp.Text =  string.Join(" ", explodedString);
```

As indexes are modified in the `string[]` array. You are required to join array to get modified `string[]` array.

**Updated Code Snippet**:

```
char[] seperator = { ' ' };
String[] explodedString = Results1[index].Key.Split(seperator);
List<String> Query= new List<string>(TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToLowerInvariant().Split(seperator,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

for (int i = 0; i < explodedString.Length; i++)
{
    if (Query.Contains(explodedString[i].ToLowerInvariant()) == true)
    {
       explodedString[i] = "<strong>" + explodedString[i] + "</strong>"; //changed
    }
}

Literal temp = new Literal();
temp.Text = string.Join(" ", explodedString); //changed 
TryCurrentWindow[index] = new KeyValuePair<Literal, string>(temp, Results1[index].Value);
```